# Can't delete all files in a directory in servlet in NetBeans

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, directory, delete-file

I can't delete all files in a directory. It's a servlet application in NetBeans.

```
 public void updateRootFile(String directorypath, String appID, String[] appName) throws IOException { 
    FileInputStream  finStream =null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    OutputStreamWriter outStream = null;
    FileInputStream  fins = null;

    String strLine="";       

    try {      
        File[] listOfFiles = fileLists("D:\\root\\");
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            String rootFiles = listOfFiles[i].getName();

            File rootFile = new File("D:/root/"+rootFiles);           
            File copyFile = new File("D:/root1/"+rootFiles);

            finStream = new FileInputStream(rootFile);

            //String propertyStr = "root.label." + appID;
            //properties.load(new InputStreamReader(finStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            //String getAppName = properties.getProperty("root.label." + appID);
            //String toUtf =new String(appName[i].getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8")  ;
            //String oldChar =  propertyStr + "=" + getAppName;
            //String newChar = propertyStr + "=" + toUtf;

            fins = new FileInputStream(rootFile);

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fins, "UTF-8"));
            outStream = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(copyFile), "UTF-8");
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {               
                strLine = strLine.replace("hai", "haai");
                outStream.write(strLine);
                outStream.write("\r\n");
            }
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            br.close();
            fins.close();
            finStream.close();                
        }                 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Excpetion : " + e);
    } 

    File rootFileone = new File("D:/root");     
    boolean check= deleteDir(rootFileone);      
}


public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i=1; i<children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            //if (!success) {
             //   return false;
           // }
        }
    }
    // The directory is now empty so delete it
    return dir.delete();
}


private  File[] fileLists(String directorypath) {
    folder = new File(directorypath);
    listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    return listOfFiles;
}
```

I have 29  `.properties` files in folder. But in this loop always at least one file remains non deleted. Hence I can't delete the folder.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: Now what is the problem with my question? Please reply

Comment: Where do you actually delete your files?

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: where means?

Comment: @Michael Petrotta:I edited 29 files in a folder and copied those 29 files to an another new folder. Now I want to delete old folder and reneme the new folder to old one's name. Now the issue is most time atleast one file remains in the olde folder as non deleted. So I cnaot delete the folder also.

Answer (score 2):

A file cannot be deleted if it's been opened by something else.

There are a lot of possible causes for this, both inside and outside your own code. I'll assume that you're managing those files exclusively inside your own code. You need to make sure that you're calling `close()` method on the `InputStream`/`OutputStream` or `Reader`/`Writer` in the `finally` block of the `try` block where you're reading/writing the file.

So, make sure that you adhere the following Java IO idiom of creating, using and closing the `InputStream`/`OutputStream` and `Reader`/`Writer` resources.

```
Writer writer = null;

try {
    writer = new FileWriter(file); // Just an example. Can be any Writer.
    writer.write(something);
    // ...
} finally {
    if (writer != null) try { writer.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
}
```

Or when you're already on [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
try (Writer writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
    writer.write(something);
    // ...
}
```

It will auto-close the `AutoCloseable` resource when the `try` block is left.

Comment: I tried. But did not make any change. I shall add the full code in my question.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory()` to delete a directory recursively?